# Obtaining RGB colors

Tags: python, colors, rgb

So I was looking how to get a list of RGB colors depending on a desired total of colors to retrieve and I found this piece of code. And there's a part that I can't understand, I already read the notes where the ">>" and "&" operators are bitwise operators but I can't fully understand what they are doing.

Can anybody help me on understanding the part where the colors values
are been assigned?

```
def getDinstinctRGBColorsList(desiredColors)
    availableColors = 16000000
    inc = availableColors/desiredColors
    colorsList = {}
    RGB = 0
    count = 0
    while count <= desiredColors:
        RGB = RGB+inc
        colorBlue = RGB & 255
        colorGreen = (RGB >> 8) & 255
        colorRed = (RGB >> 16) & 255
        colorsList[count] = str(colorRed) + "," + str(colorGreen) + "," + str(colorBlue)
        count += 1
    return colorsList
```

Comment: `&` is bitwise and operator. `>>` is bitwise right shift operator. They are both [documented here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) which you can find with simple search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [BitwiseOperators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) and [What are bitwise shift (bit-shift) operators and how do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/what-are-bitwise-shift-bit-shift-operators-and-how-do-they-work).

From the code you posted, it looks like `RGB` contains 24 bits of color information: 8 bits for red, 8 bits for green, and 8 bits for blue with the red data in the left most 8 bits, the green data in the middle 8 bits, and the blue data in the right most 8 bits.

Imagine the bits of `RGB` look like `0brrrrrrrrggggggggbbbbbbbb` where `r` is a bit for the red value, `g` is a bit for the green value, and `b` is a bit for the blue value.

Note that `255` in binary is `0b11111111` (8 set bits).

`colorGreen = (RGB >> 8) & 255` is extracting the middle 8 bits that represent green using `>>` (right shift) and `&` (bitwise and):

`0brrrrrrrrggggggggbbbbbbbb >> 8` yields `0b00000000rrrrrrrrgggggggg`

Note how the bits for green are now the left-most 8 bits. However, the bits for red are still present.

`0b00000000rrrrrrrrgggggggg & 0b00000000000000001111111` yields `0b0000000000000000gggggggg`

Note how only the bits for green remain.

Edit: This is a simplification. In Python, `>>` is an arithmetic shift, not a logical shift. An arithmetic shift preserves sign. See [What are bitwise shift (bit-shift) operators and how do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/what-are-bitwise-shift-bit-shift-operators-and-how-do-they-work) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you I was getting a headache while trying to understand this.